# Azure Hybrid Connection does not connect to my on premise database

Tags: azure, azure-hybrid-connections

I have this web API in azure https://fysegplannerapi.azurewebsites.net/api/proyectos that

That makes queries to an on-premise database in my data center in the physical office

In order to reach this database I have associated a hybrid connection end point to the web API

[image: hybrid connection]

In a server of my LAN I have installed the connection manager and I have it connected

[image: gestor]

But it turns out that in another Azure subscription I am trying the same thing with another webAPI that attacks the same database on premise but I can't get it to work

https://boletusapi.azurewebsites.net/api/proyectossap

[image: error]

I have associated this endpoint

[image: end point boletus]

[image: gestor boletus]

I can't understand where the error is or what I'm missing

Any idea, please?

Thanks

Comment: have you ever figured this out? Have the same problem